# AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'exclude'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I build the notification system, and I want to exclude the author of the post when adding like to their own post so of receiving the notification, I facing this problem

my view

```
def add_remove_like(request, pk):
data = {}
video = Video.objects.get(pk=pk)

if request.method == "POST":
    user = request.user
    if video.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
        liked = False
        video.likes.remove(user)
    else:
        video.likes.add(user)

        instance = video.author
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)

        try:
            notify = Notify.objects.create(from_user=request.user.exclude(from_user=instance), target=instance, content_type=content_type,
                                           redirect_url=f"{settings.BASE_URL}/video/account/video/{video.pk}",
                                           object_id=instance.pk,
                                           verb=f"{request.user} added like to your video"
                                           )
            notify.timestamp = timezone.now()
            notify.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.user` is an object, not queryset. So `exclude` won't work here. So you can update the code like this:

```
from_user = request.user if request.user != instance else None
notify = Notify.objects.create(
    from_user= from_user,
    target=instance,
    content_type=content_type,
    redirect_url=f"{settings.BASE_URL}/video/account/video/{video.pk}",
    object_id=instance.pk,
    verb=f"{request.user} added like to your video",
    timestamp=timezone.now()
)
```

I have removed other codes like `notify.save()` because it is redandent if you add timestamp in the queryset's `create` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The author of the post still receive the likes that he added to his post

Comment: @MohamedSoliman basically, @ruddra has solved the problem with AttributeError, but if you don't want the author to receive notifications from himself, you need to add extra checks like: if video.author != request.user, then create `Notify`, else do nothing.

Comment: @ErsainD Thank you it's worked after I added `if request.user == instance:`